# Failed create feign client in spring boot auto configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

I would like to create a custom autoconfig in external library which is a feign client interface
But when I point the auto configuration by

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=
com.hello.world.MyFeginClient

When I build my springBoot, I am failed to initiate the service
Failed to instantiate : Specified class is an interface

If I want to put my fegin client in my autoconfiguarion, what should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this dependency added in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also you need to add this annotation @EnableFeignClients which scans for the @FeignClient

```
@EnableFeignClients
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication .class, args);
    }
}
```